# Replacing Tab(s) with a Space - Memory Issues (free invalid next size fast)

Tags: c

I am trying to pass a string with tab(s) in it to a function, and have the function replace each tab, or repeating tabs with a space. The problem I am having is regarding memory issues. Here is my code:

```
void ConvertToOneSpace(char *dst, char *src) {
    int i, j, first_tab = 1;

    for(i = 0, j = 0; src[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (src[i] == '\t' && first_tab == 0) continue;
        if (src[i] == '\t' && first_tab == 1) {
            first_tab = 0;
            dst[j] = ' ';
        } else {
            first_tab = 1;
            dst[j] = src[j];
        }
        j++;
    }
    dst[j] = '\0';
}

int PrintComment(char *desc) {
    char aString[4096];
    char *result = NULL;

    strcpy(aString, desc);
    result = strtok(aString, "\n");
    while(result != NULL) {
        result_notabs = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(result)));
        ConvertToOneSpace(result_notabs, result);
        printf("%s\n", result_notabs);
        /* Code that operates on result_notabs, splitting it into multiple sub
            strings of shorter length. This code was tested working perfectly 
            before implementing and utilizing ConvertToOneSpace */
        free(result_notabs);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I run PrintComment() on multiple strings (hundreds), with random print statements to verify everything is working as should. It does, until what appears to be a random string (nothing special about it that I can tell) and I get the following error:

```
     free(): invalid next size (fast)
```

I am assuming it is memory related, because when I valgrind it (with memcheck), it works perfectly. Can anyone spot the error? I am assuming it isnt in the other code I have left out (as the comment says, that was working perfectly before implementing this).

Thanks!

Comment: Note that in `PrintComment()`, you declare `aString` as an array of pointer to char, but you then proceed to use it as an array of char.

Comment: where is result_notabs defined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line

```
result_notabs = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(result)));
```

should be

```
result_notabs = malloc(strlen(result) + 1);
```

to leave space for the null terminator at the end of `result`.  Without this, `ConvertToOneSpace` writes beyond the end of `result_notabs`.  This has undefined consequences which could include writing to memory used by other parts of your program.

Note that I made a couple of other changes to that line

- removed the cast from the return of `malloc`.  This isn't required in C and [can mask bugs](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html)
- removed the use of `sizeof(char)` since this is guaranteed to be 1

You should also note the comment from Elchonon Edelson.

```
char *aString[4096];
```

declares an array of 4096 `char` *pointers*.  Your code just needs an array of `char`s instead

```
char aString[4096];
```

(This won't have caused your problem but its worth getting into the habit of using the correct type for strings)

Comment: And, you did it correctly but you shall be mentioning it explicitly, not to cast the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: @H2CO3 Fair point, I've done this now

Comment: Just as a side note, that line was at one point `result_notabs = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(result) + 1));`, therefore meanining the solution in this case was one of the other changes you made, which I would have never guessed. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @halexh If that's the case, I'd guess that you're missing an include of `<stdlib.h>`.  If correcting this doesn't help, there may be another bug in the code that I haven't spotted.  Can you try applying my suggested changes first and see if that helps (or even just changes the point at which your program crashes)?

Comment: Yea. I applied your suggestion, and that fixed the issue. Since there were multiple changes to that one line, I was just clarifying that the + 1 was probably not the issue, since that line did include the + 1 at one point. Also, the char *aString[4096] was just a typo here on stackoverflow. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use  `result_notabs = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(result)+1)));` instead of  `result_notabs = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(result)));`
Here extra 1 is added to string length for the terminating null charecter.